# Customer Data error after logging in as a customer

Tags: magento-2.1, login, customer-session

I add some products (esp. Configurable product) in the cart and when I login I get following customer data error.

[image]

When I click on the error it redirects me to the following error

[image]

Due to which my cart gets empty. To manually fix this issue, I have to add a simple product (for eg: bag) and then my cart shows products including the configurable product, and when I delete any product from cart, I don't get the customer-data error again.

Can someone please give me a permanent solution to the above problem?